# How to make a div fit to screen without the other divs being visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

One of the divs which i want to display dynamically has to fit to screen. The problem is that if the earlier displayed div has height more than the screen height, when the dynamic div is displayed in the bottom of the page(after scrolling) there is some part of the earlier div still remaining. I dont want any trace of the earlier while displaying the dynamic div. Also i have to achieve this only by using javascript.

Comment: Try `height` and `witdh` set in `%` or `em`.

Comment: I tried but it dosent work.                        `document.getElementById('pt-main').style.width = "100%";
            document.getElementById('pt-main').style.height = "100%";
           document.getElementById('pt-main').style.display = "none";`

Comment: Can you show your code in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the div out of your other divs, but still in the body and make it not visible "display:none;"

Give it some attributes, like Mardzis said, height : 100%; width : 100%; z-index:9999;

Then, when you want to display it, just do .show() or .hide() (with jquery if you use it) or .getElementById('#yourDivId').style.display = "none"; .... & so on...

Comment: do not set the width & height with js... 
<div style="display:none;height:100%;width:100%;z-index:9999;" id="yourDiv">HEY</div>
AND, as @veerasuthan V said, you can place it with position:absolute;top:0;left:0; (still in the style property). Then just play with jquery .hide() / .show()... that should work like this

Comment: No i cant use html. limitation of my architecture.

Comment: @Query21 Do you know the "biggest div" id? or is it dynamic?

Comment: No the biggest div was created in html with id pt-main.

Comment: Thanks. Although this resizes the test div to parent div size. I guess resizing parent div dynamically is not possible.

Comment: @Query21 it is possible, but here, "#main" is NOT parent of "#test", test is detached... if it was parent, you can get it with something like $("#test").parent... (i think). It is possible to resize the other div, just change the id in the $("#")... first, understand the logic, then edit and make it fit your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

to place an div or any element one above another use position:absolute,top:0; left:0 and width and height to 100%

Comment: My earlier div is the main div that can have width and height more than 100%. So this i cant do.

Comment: <div id="parentDiv"><div class="innerDiv" id="div1"></div><div  id="div2" class="innerDiv"></div><div class="innerDiv" id="div3"></div></div>

parentDiv - should be position relative width and height to screen width
innerDiv - Postion absolute and width,height to 100%

toggle innerDiv based on user clicks

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this.Put focus on the child div and disable scrolling.